# Should I flag or should I edit out a social network promotion myself?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, self-promotion

I found an answer with this at the end:

> [image]

We all agree that such content should not belong in an answer but is it worth flagging or can I simply edit out that content? I found it in 2 answers by the same user (there are probably more). Is it ok if I clean up such content from their answers or is it a moderator-only job?

Comment: So you got to let me know: should I flag or should I go?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22follow+me+on+instagram%22+site:stackoverflow.com shows surprising little of this if one excludes code snippets and user profiles (where I guess it's OK).

Comment: Please upvote my answer and **smash that subscribe button**.

Comment: @abligh Since promotion of one's social network profile is regularly edited out from posts when discovered, it's not surprising to me at all that you can't find many examples of it.

Answer (score 48):

If you happen to come upon an answer that answers the question, I would suggest simply editing out the link to their instagram, and leaving a comment that they shouldn't do this in the future. Something like:

> I've edited out the link to your instagram account. Please don't promote your own content in posts. This is not allowed, and if you repeat this, you will be considered a spammer. You are allowed to share such links in your profile page, so feel free to do that if you want to.

You could also link to the [/help/promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) page in your comment. This should be sufficient for any user who's just unaware of the rules, and has made an honest mistake. I would suggest not raising a flag based just on this answer, as it's likely to be declined. A Spam flag in particular is very likely to get declined: affiliation is disclosed, and in just a single answer, that content is more noise than *overt self-promotion*, and can simply be edited out.

However, if you see a pattern of such answers where the user promotes their own content, then you should raise a custom flag explaining the situation, as moderators have better tooling at their disposal to investigate such matters. I would define "pattern" quite loosely, e.g. even two such answers from the same user would count. You can still edit *one* of their answers and leave a comment underneath it. It's certainly possible that the user goes and removes the content from their other posts, but you shouldn't rely on that. I also recommend not editing out the promotional content from multiple answers by the same user.

Also, if they ignore your comment, and add back the promotional part to the answer, then raise a custom flag even if it's their only such answer. Such behavior by the user indicates they are not willing to listen to reason, and only moderators have the ability to deal with those situations.

Comment: *I would suggest not raising a Spam flag based just on this answer, as it's likely to be declined.* --> I wan't going to raise a spam flag but a custom one like you explained later

Comment: @TemaniAfif Right, I know you know not to do that but I figured I should make that clear in the answer anyway. I imagine some users would think that a spam flag would be ok for this.

Comment: The /help/promotion page does not say it's not allowed - it only says it tends to get downvoted. I don't see why (in general) a somewhat relevant link would be forbidden if it is just supplementary to the answer? Such a suggestion can be useful? And if it is not, then it is noise just like "Thank you very much and all the best to you!"

Comment: @lucidbrot I'm not sure what you mean. The first line of /help/promotion says "*The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion **and flag it as spam***" (My emphasis). It's noise if it's just in a single post, but beyond that, I would be way less sympathetic, *especially* given that it's an invitation to visit their instagram account and "learn more", which means it's not relevant to the question they're answering. Also, while it's called noise when it's in a single post, it's *very* different from "thanks" comments. No amount of those is ever going to invite a Spam flag.

Comment: @cigien Ah, I interpreted that as description of what usually happens, not whether it's actually supposed to happen. I agree that an unrelated "follow me on insta" is useless and should not be allowed... but e.g. if you're often answering beginner answers and you have written a good tutorial, I see no issue with mentioning it often, as long as it is helpful to OP.

Comment: "Please don't promote your own content in posts" - IMHO, there's a difference between promoting my contents and promoting myself. I agree, people should not be using this platform to get social media followers. But, if I have code on a github repo that is relevant to the question, there's nothing wrong with including that link, right? Maybe I am reading too much into this, but this is somewhat sensitive to me as I was banned from Reddit for "self promoting" for linking relevant work from videos or blogs on the topic, instead of "copying and pasting" the same info on Reddit.

Comment: @hfontanez This post is about *irrelevant* links, which is a different thing. Note however, that if you repeatedly link to your own content, *even if* affiliation is disclosed, *and* it's relevant, you can be considered a spammer. It's a subjective call of course, but if say, you have 5 answers, and all of them link to your content, then you are likely to be flagged as a spammer, and you could be sanctioned. I don't know anything about Reddit's policy in this regard, so I can't speak to that. cc lucidbrot.

Comment: Yeah, mentioning the same link in 5 out of 100 useful answers is generally fine, but 5/5 would usually only happen if someone went looking for questions where they could post an answer that includes a link to their project.  That *could* be acceptable if the answers are all significantly different from each other and useful (fully tailored to the questions, not a thin excuse to link), and on questions that didn't already have good answers, but that situation sounds very rare.  (cc @lucidbrot, see cigien's previous comment, which I'm replying to)

Comment: Yeah, edit it, only flag if OP refuses to see reason. Mods generally have enough work on their plate, so user corrections minimise this. In any case, "follow me on Insta" comments should probably be in someone's bio, not their answers.

Comment: I'd just point them to placing stuff like that in their profile where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

**Context for Self-Promotion FAQ**

As has already been pointed out, we have [help/promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in the FAQ. It might be worth adding some additional context, though. That FAQ was written to address promoting products or projects that are owned or maintained by the post author. Even when those products are relevant, the association with the author has caused some heartburn. That FAQ post was meant to help settle the issue. See: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/191410). I don't think that FAQ post really intended to cover an author's social media profile link.

**Social media links are not a special case**

It may help to reframe the question, because ultimately I don't care who the author of the linked content is. What matters is if it helps me to find an answer to the question. In this sense, social media links are not a special case. They should be treated as any other content. If an answer contains content that is clearly not relevant to the question, it is generally appropriate to edit out that content (i.e. "Thanks for reading!" or "I hope it helps!").

In [/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) we have the following section:

> **Provide context for links**
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

The corollary principle of "*quote the most relevant part*" would be that if there's nothing relevant enough to quote, then the link is suspect. For some questions, it may make sense to link to some general documentation, such as pointing a new practitioner to a technology's wiki (so long as it's not a link-only answer). In those cases, a quotation might not be necessary, but I'd still expect the author to explain how, specifically, the link would be useful in regards to the question.

**Not all social media links are irrelevant**

It takes a bit of wisdom to discern whether a social media link is appropriate and relevant. There's a spectrum. If the link points to a social media account that is highly specialized and relevant to the question, such as an account dedicated to SQL injection attack awareness where the question is about about that general topic, then it *might* be useful. If the social media account is very general and not especially relevant, such as a personal account containing recent vacation photos and only occasional technical posts on a wide variety of topics, then I'd edit it out.

**Dealing with habitual insertion of irrelevant content**

If a user is habitually adding irrelevant content to their posts, then you may want to gently correct that behavior in a comment. If the user persists or attempts to add that irrelevant content back to their posts, then a custom flag is appropriate. Avoid edit wars. Raise the post to a moderator's attention and leave.