# How can I handle off-site contact links in the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-promotion

How do I handle [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417975/spawns-only-1-enemy-but-amount-of-enemies-to-spawn-is-5) that refers to social media options when contacting the person about this question, namely [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord) and [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software))? Is this behavior allowed on this site? Do we have any guidelines for that? Because it's not a "Look at my social media"-type of answer that is described [in the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) or seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405195/should-i-flag-or-should-i-edit-out-a-social-network-promotion-myself/405280). It's just a nod to "if you want to see more of my code, come there". Is this considered flag-worthy or should we just inform the person that this is not desired on SO?

My initial reaction would be to just tell the person that, if they want help, they have to add more information on SO instead of trying to lure me away from it. This is a Q&A database after all and solving the problem outside of SO could probably invalidate the usefulness of the question.

Comment: This is similar to [Asking for help via email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297249/asking-for-help-via-email). There it was suggested to close as too broad.

Comment: No, it's not allowed to include off-site contact information in a question or otherwise request that a question be answered off-site. Raise a custom moderator flag. Under normal circumstances (i.e., when Stack Overflow moderators are not striking), we have and use a moderator message template for precisely this case.

Comment: Only close as lacking focus/too broad if it *actually is* too broad. If they've omitted details because they expect you to contact them elsewhere, then that's either lacking focus or possibly needing a minimal, reproducible example. But don't close it merely because it contains off-site contact info. That can be edited out and a moderator flag raised. @Marijn

Comment: @chivracq You are right, I will rephrase the question in this regard and replace "social media" with "off-site contact info". But I feel there is a big difference between a link to a messenger like Discord and a GitHub repository: The information on a messenger vanishes after the topic is talked about, either by a flood of text or in a voice chat. A GitHub link is just a link to another open website, it could also be a link to a blog or the documentation.

Comment: Alright, I've deleted my 2 previous Comments, the Edit from "*social media links*" into "off-site contact links*" addressed them perfectly... // I think Mod @CodyGray "should"/could convert their 2 Comments into an Answer, with '+29' & '+14' Upvotes they convey the most Support from the Community for the "Situation" described in the Qt... (After the Strike I suppose...(?))

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike If the question is not too broad and can be answered on-site, is it acceptable to just edit the question and leave a comment? Or does the principle still apply and should raise a mod flag?

Comment: @MichaelM. Yeah, editing to correct the problem yourself is reasonable, *especially* if it's the first offense. Probably not worth involving a moderator until it becomes a pattern of behavior and/or the user indicates that they're not going to listen to anyone else.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The whole premise of this site is that questions and answers must be *self-contained* to help future visitors to this Q&A knowledge base. Any sort of incentive for an asker or answerer to leave the site is trying to turn it into a support forum, is thus against the rules. Further, invitations to leave the site are often spam or worse, attempts by bad actors to trick users into having their personal information stolen.

Flag for moderator attention and move on.

(In this case the Meta effect had the welcome effect of closing the question because it's an atrocious piece of rubbish that violated the most basic rules for asking here, so a mod flag wasn't needed.)

Comment: "so a mod flag wasn't needed" - I still flagged it after the comments came in. Good thing, this topic is done. Will flag in the future again!